# Comparing Stack and Queue Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

Design patterns from http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/

[image]

```
public interface Comparable {
    boolean isLT (Comparable object);
    boolean isLE (Comparable object);
    boolean isGT (Comparable object);
    boolean isGE (Comparable object);
    boolean isEQ (Comparable object);
    boolean isNE (Comparable object);
    int compare (Comparable object);
}


public interface Container extends Comparable{
    int getCount();
    boolean isEmpty();
    boolean isFull();
    void purge();
    Enumeration getEnumeration();
}


public interface Queue extends Container { 
    Object getHead() throws ContainerEmptyException;
    void enqueue (Object object) throws ContainerFullException;
    Object dequeue() throws ContainerEmptyException;
}
```

Other than `number of elements`, what are other sensible criteria we can use to compare stack and queue.

Comment: This seems like a fairly opinion-based/broad question, as there isn't really a definitive list of ways to compare the two.

Comment: I wouldn't have made Container implement Comparable.  That interface should be used when there is a natural comparison.  I'm not going  to make that an answer, as it is indeed just my humble opinion, and this question is likely to be closed as opinion-based.